How do I reduce the text values to 4 decimals in the shap force plot. I do not want to rotate the text?
enter image description here
In this image, I have the variables where there are lots of numbers after decimal point. I need to reduce it to 3 or 4.
shap.plots.force(shap_values[0], matplotlib=True,figsize=(40,3))

I tried to rotate the text but it doesn't look good.

I think this answer could help you.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/455634/20334819

@Yocapell, Thank you that helped me, I tried to round up the variables and found that the explanatory variable is immutable, so made a copy and rounded them, it worked.
